# react-router-dom doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

It looks like i have some problem with react-router-dom package if i try to install it i have this warning (see the screenshot):

> npm WARN react-router-dom@4.0.0 requires a peer of react@^15 but none
>   is installed. 
> You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>  npm
>   WARN react-router@4.2.0 requires a peer of react@>=15 but none is
>   installed.
>  You must install peer dependencies yourself.

I also tried to update all the packages but with bad results.

Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Your react version is way outdated. I'd suggest to update it first, and then deal with the problems that may arise from that update alone.

Comment: I have this packages installed "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "4.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  }

Comment: but i have always the same problem.  This kind of error :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shape' of undefined
    at Object._extends (bundle.js:18420)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:18337)
    at Object.exports.__esModule (bundle.js:18408)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.exports.__esModule (bundle.js:18313)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:66)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:47)

Comment: I suggest you update your `react-redux` package to the last version, currently 5.0.7.

Answer (score 5):

Follow the below steps.

1. Delete your node_modules.
2. Remove react, react-router and react-router-dom  dependencies from
   package.json file.
3. and then try **npm install react react-router react-router-dom --save**.

hope so this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have react-router-dom of v 4.0.0, and a react of v 0.14.3. It's time to upgrade your react. The error has made it clear that react-router-dom requires react of > 15 but you are at 0.14.3.

Step 1:

delete the react, react-dom, react-redux, and redux from node_modules

Step2:

update your package.json with latest versions of these packages: react, react-dom, react-redux, redux. As of now, their versions are:

```
"react": "^16.4.1",
"react-dom": "^16.4.1",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"redux": "^4.0.0",
```

step3:

npm install

This should fix the problem permanently.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed react? Can you first try to execute below command and then install react-router-dom:
npm install react --save